# Why does hash.keys.class return Arrays?

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby, I'm just missing something basic here. Are the keys in a Hash considered an Array unto themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `Hash#keys` returns the hash's keys as a *new* array, i.e., the hash and the array returned by `Hash#keys` are completely independent of each other:

```
a = {}
b = a.keys
c = a.keys

b << :foo

a   # still {}
b   # [:foo]
c   # still []

a[:bar] = :baz

a   # {:bar => :baz}
b   # still [:foo]
c   # still []
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it is a new array and changes to it will not affect the underlying hash.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of hash.keys:

> > Returns a new array populated with the keys from this hash. See also Hash#values.

So the class is Array because the return value is an array.

About your question "Are the keys in a Hash considered an Array unto themselves?", they "kind" of are, hashes in Ruby are implemented as struct (st_table) which contains a list of pointers to each of its entries(st_table_entry),the st_table_entry contains the key and its value, so I guess what the keys method does is just transversing that list taking out each of the keys.

You can read this article of Ilya Grigorik where he explains much better Hashes in Ruby http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/

Answer (score -2):

Do you think there's something paradoxical about this? Keep in mind that hashes aren't arrays in Ruby.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to take from your response. I asked a pretty straightforward question, admitting complete ignorance... Not sure your response qualifies as an "answer", though the part about hashes not being arrays is helpful.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: I was just trying to clarify your question. You can tell by doing `{}.keys.class` that keys are indeed an Array. I was just asking if you were surprised by this behaviour. If you think there is something surprising about it, then describing why you think it's surprising would help me answer your question better. Did you downvote me because of this?

Comment: Wouldn't qualify this as an answer. More appropriate as comment question